# separate column into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this table

```
id  Name     Phone      Emails
1   abc,def  980,987    abc@,def@
2   aaa,bb   555,44     aaa@,bb
3   cc,gg    43
```

and i need to get this table

```
id  Name    Phone   Emails
1   abc     980     abc@
1   def     987     def@
2   aaa     555     aaa@
2   bb      44      bb
3   cc      43  
3   gg
```

any suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried, why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate of your other question, but it certainly has the same answer:

```
with cte as (
      select id, convert(varchar(max), null) as name, convert(varchar(max), null)  as phone, convert(varchar(max), null)  as email,
             convert(varchar(max), names + ',') as names_rest,
             convert(varchar(max), phones + ',') as phones_rest,
             convert(varchar(max), emails + ',') as emails_rest,
             0 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select id, left(names_rest, charindex(',', names_rest) - 1),
             left(phones_rest, charindex(',', phones_rest) - 1),
             left(emails_rest, charindex(',', emails_rest) - 1),
             stuff(names_rest, 1, charindex(',', names_rest), ''),
             stuff(phones_rest, 1, charindex(',', phones_rest), ''),
             stuff(emails_rest, 1, charindex(',', emails_rest), ''),
             lev + 1
      from cte
      where names_rest like '%,%'
     )
select id, name, phone, email
from cte
where lev > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d9902e6a478d627b63bdb607d3af632e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: yes it's the same but with more details and with examples. 
thanks for your replay (fast one :) )
its perfact! 
i get an error because of my data its measi 
but your solution work!